# Gradle ivy-publisher for publishing libs/headers into Artifactory

Tags: gradle, ivy, artifactory

We have a project in Visual Studio that after compilation creates a build folder with multiple dll files and header files.

In our CI server we want to push these as a single "artifact" to an Artifactory server, and have a single version identifier for this artifact. It looks like Gradle + Ivy with multiple files per artifact can do this. But there is no documentation on this and no examples that we could find.

How can we use Gradle to push a single versioned artifact that includes multiple files to Artifactory?

Comment: As far as I know artifactory should have API for uploading artifacts. Google for the docs and implement a task that does it.